# Can Android see my Tor traffic? Running Tor over Tails

Tags: tails, android

I was spending a lot of time investigating cryptocurrencies using Tor over Tails, mostly Wiki. When I closed browser and opened Twitter on my Android there were crypto ads all over! Bluetooth on both devices off and App permissions/Google settings set for privacy. I don't usually get these ads. Just a coincidence?

Answer (score 0):

The connections in Tails are carefully routed through Tor, and Bluetooth is disabled IIRC, an interception in-the-wild from your smartphone is not the most probable.
You may want to consider these possibilities:

- You used a personal online account while browsing with Tails, connecting your 'anonymous' activity to your usual identity.
- You pay more attention to crypto ads.
- Your behaviors are too predictable